# R quarto full page width render to PDF {gt} tables

Tags: r, pdf-generation, quarto

I'd like to use the full page width when rendering a quarto file to PDF without modifying the margins for the entire document or the paper size. I have a table I've built using the {gt} package that is running off the page along with some screen shots that I'd like set side by side.

The workaround I have now is saving the {gt} table as a png and `knitr::include_graphics('..')` which still doesn't look great.

The [quarto-documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/article-layout.html) describes how to achieve this when rendering to HTML, but it is not working when outputting to PDF.

**tldr:** I want a code chunk to take the full page width when rendering a quarto document to pdf.

Below is what I've tried - also open to a latex solution.

````
---
title: "test-file"
format: 
  pdf:
    keep-tex: false
    echo: false
    warning: false
    documentclass: scrreprt
    classoption: [landscape]
    papersize: letter
    pagestyle: plain
    geometry: 
      - left=1in
      - right=1in

---

# Quarto

::: {.column-screen-inset}
```{r}
library(tidyverse)
cbind(mtcars, mtcars[,2:10]) %>% 
  as_tibble(.name_repair = 'unique') %>% 
  gt::gt()
  
```
:::

```{r}
#| column: screen-inset-shaded
#| layout-nrow: 1

cbind(mtcars, mtcars[,2:10]) %>% 
  as_tibble(.name_repair = 'unique') %>% 
  gt::gt()
  
```


::: {.column-margin}

We know from *the first fundamental theorem of calculus* that for $x$ in $[a, b]$:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left( \int_{a}^{x} f(u)\,du\right)=f(x).$$
:::

Has no effect on output... 

::: {.column-screen-left}

```{r}
#| column: screen-inset-left

mtcars %>% 
gt::gt()
```

:::
````

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
format: 
  pdf:
    documentclass: article
    geometry:
      - top=30mm
      - left=20mm
      - heightrounded
```